# How to disable `tree-sitter-hl-mode` for `org-mode`/`markdown-mode` code blocks?

Tags: hooks, minor-mode

My `tree-sitter` setting is

```
;; Tree-sitter highlight
;; Base framework, syntax highlighting.
(use-package tree-sitter
  :diminish (tree-sitter-mode)
  :hook ((after-init . global-tree-sitter-mode)
         (tree-sitter-after-on . tree-sitter-hl-mode)))

;; Language bundle.
(use-package tree-sitter-langs
  :demand t
  :after tree-sitter)
```

and it plays well with source code files. I don't want to use it (`tree-sitter`) in `org-mode`/`markdown-mode` code blocks (note that, I mean in an `org-mode`/`markdown-mode` buffer, not `org-src-mode` buffer), but I do want basic native syntax highlight without `tree-sitter` in code blocks (i.e. keep `org-src-fontify-natively`/`markdown-fontify-code-blocks-natively` to `t`).

How can I disable it in these cases?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: If you aren't seeing any fontification, you need to show us how the src blocks looks like ....

---

- What is the value of `org-edit-src-content-indentation` on your side?
- How does your source blocks look like?
- It matters if they have leading whitespace etc.  For example, with this setting

```lisp
(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)
```

titles in `markdown-mode` blocks do get fontified.

---

#### Source block fontification in `org-mode-9.5.4` with `tree-sitter-hl-mode`

- Leading whitespace may affect fontification
- Comma-quoted `org` lines aren't fontified

[image: Source block fontification in org-mode with tree-sitter-hl-mode on: (a) Leading whitespace affects fontification (b) Comma-quoted lines aren't fontified]

#### Test snippet

```
#+begin_src python
# install the apport exception handler if available
try:
    import apport_python_hook
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    apport_python_hook.install()
#+end_src

# Following block were created with
# ~(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 0)~

#+begin_src markdown
# testing
## testing 2
#+end_src

#+begin_src org
,#+title: *An Org Snippet*

,* a
,** b

# This  is comment

- A :: First alphabet
- B :: Second *alphabet*
#+end_src

# Following block were created with
# ~(setq org-edit-src-content-indentation 2)~

#+begin_src markdown
  # testing
  ## testing 2
#+end_src

#+begin_src org
  ,#+title: *An Org Snippet*

  ,* a
  ,** b

  # This  is comment

  - A :: First alphabet
  - B :: Second *alphabet*
#+end_src
```

Both `markdown-mode` and `org-mode` blocks are fontified natively.

- In `markdown-mode` presence of leading whitespace before the title renders the "title" string as regular text.
- In `org-mode` source blocks, the fontification doesn't happen for lines with  *quoting commas* introduced by `org-edit-special`. `org-mode` fontification doesn't `unquote` or `de-indent` before fontification.  (I think) `org-mode` should adjust face positions on in-buffer text,  after accounting for *displacements* caused by leading indentation or quoting commas. See [`org-src-font-lock-fontify-block`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/org/org-src.el?h=8b31c18fc8669e3b6e493769c7e033ddea08375c#n616)

---

You confirm that `python-mode` blocks are fontified by treesitter by doing `C-u C-x =` on the fontified text, and ensuring that the face name has a `tree-sitter` prefix.

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 (tree-sitter-hl-face:keyword org-block)
  font-lock-fontified  t
  font-lock-multiline  t
  fontified            t
  src-block            t
```

You can confirm that `org-mode` and `markdown-mode` blocks are fontified by `Emacs` modes by doing `C-u C-x =` on the fontified text, and ensuring that it does NOT have the `tree-sitter` prefix.

```
There are text properties here:
  face                 (tree-sitter-hl-face:keyword org-block)
  font-lock-fontified  t
  font-lock-multiline  t
  fontified            t
  src-block            t
```

Comment: Hi, I do get syntax highlight with/without `tree-sitter-hl-mode` in `org` blocks. The real issue for me is: `tree-sitter-hl-mode` is enabled for `org` blocks and I use variable fonts (by `buffer-face-mode`) for `org-mode` thus some of the `tree-sitter` faces then use variable fonts I set for `buffer-face-mode`. Looking into the definitions of `tree-sitter-*-faces` and I see that all of them inherits from the `default` face. I could custom all these faces but I prefer a simple way to just disable `tree-sitter-hl-mode` for `org` blocks, which may also improve fortified performance.

Comment: Why don't you set a screenshot of what you have?  I was the one who replied to your `buffer-face-mode` query, so I have *some idea* of what you could be saying.  To better understand the issue, why don't you share your minimal config and screenshots (with comments of expected behaviour)